# Unable to join VM to AD - cannot complete this function

Tags: dns, active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I am having a VMs in Azure and AD VM also in Azure. They are all in same network, although in different subnets.

I have provisioned the VM's by terraform and they are unable to join to AD, hence I am doing manually to see what the error is.

Commands to connect VM to AD is below:

```
PS C:\Users\scmadmin> $domain = "contoso.com"
PS C:\Users\scmadmin> $password = "<password here>" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
PS C:\Users\scmadmin> $username = "$domain\scmadmin"
PS C:\Users\scmadmin> $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
PS C:\Users\scmadmin> Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $credential
```

The log output after the execution is below:

```
Add-Computer : Computer 'erxprebussvc01' failed to join domain 'contoso.com' from its current workgroup 'WORKGROUP'
with following error message: Cannot complete this function.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $credential
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (erxprebussvc01:String) [Add-Computer], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailToJoinDomainFromWorkgroup,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddComputerCommand
```

At Virtual Network level, DNS Server IP is the IP (Private IP) of AD=10.112.1.4

I am able to ping domain,

```
PS C:\Users\scmadmin> ping contoso.com

Pinging contoso.com [10.112.1.4] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.112.1.4: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.112.1.4: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.112.1.4: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.112.1.4: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 10.112.1.4:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms
```

Windows Event viewer log reports the below error

```
The machine erxprebussvc01 attempted to join the domain contoso.com but failed. The error code was 1355.
```

Unable to understand what is the issue/how to troubleshoot and how to resolve it.

Comment: From the client Vm, can you do a ipconfig/all and check if you can see the AD's IP as the DNS server?

Comment: @msrini-MSITYes I can see AD Server as DNS Server

Comment: Any update on your question?

Comment: I have done exactly what you wrote. DNS records are also correct. I am investigating it further, when I get a right lead, I shall update everyone here.

Comment: Have you tried to manually join the domain in the UI? Does it pop out the box of providing credentials?

Comment: Yes manually via UI and command line I get the same error. Cannot complete this function, something on these lines...

Comment: After you change the DNS servers for the VNet, Have you reboot both your VMs on the portal?

Comment: Yes, 100%, I did several times but I am having no luck.

Comment: It's strange, you can reproduce this issue 100%? or is there any difference setting between you deploy VM via terraform and manually UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not provisioned the VMs by terraform. Instead, I manually deploy two Azure VMs (one is as AD and DNS server, the other is as Client) on the Azure portal. The steps are simple as below:

1. Deploy both VMs in a different subnet but in the same VNet.
2. Set Up server role(ADDC, DNS) on the AD server and make it as the DC server.
3. Change the DNS servers to the AD private IP address in the Azure VNet portal.
4. **Restart two Azure VMs on the Azure portal.**
5. After VM restoring running, RDP to the client VM, you can join this VM to AD domain `contoso.com` manually or via commands.

Generally, VMs in the same subnet could communicate with each other without any port limitation. So It looks like the DNS issue on your side. You can reboot your VMs or `ipconfig/flushdns` on the client VM. Or verify if the [DNS records](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Verifying_and_Creating_a_DC_DNS_Record) are created on the DC VM properly.

Moreover, you can refer to this event [error code 1355](http://www.eventid.net/errorsdisplay.asp?error_code=1355) and this troubleshooting tutorial: [How to troubleshoot errors that occur when you join Windows-based computers to a domain](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4341920/troubleshoot-errors-that-occur-when-you-join-windows-based-computers-t)